# Installing alongside windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10

I want a refresh on my laptop and I was wondering before I reinstall W10 and remake my partitions, is it better to leave some unnalocated space for UBUNTU or I can make the space after I reinstall W10 in the disk partition manager? 
If I can leave space when partitioning the hard drive for W10, can I make the root, swap and home with the unnalocated space? it wont take space from my allocated W10 space?

Answer (score 2):

If you plan dual boot, definitely leave unpartitioned space. You can shrink Windows partition later but it is far more complicated than leaving free space now.

Answer (score 0):

I would say either is alright. After installing Windows 10 you can easily shrink your Windows partition in disk management.

This is the way I did it to install Ubuntu and Windows 10 on the same hard drive:

1. Open up Disk Management on Windows
2. Right-click on your current Windows installation partition, and press shrink. Then choose by how much
3. Then you should see some unallocated space, that's where Ubuntu will be installed
4. Boot up from your Ubuntu installation media
5. Continue with normal setup and choose "Install alongside Windows 10"
6. This will create all partitions for Ubuntu to work (swap, home, etc)
7. Continue with all steps and you're done

You will realise when booting you'll get an option of Ubuntu and Windows 10, just choose the appropriate one from the list of options.

You now have Ubuntu installed alongside Windows 10.

Comment: Resizing a partition always carries some risk. Increasing the size from the end is the least risky operation, followed by shrinking the size from the end, followed by anything that adjusts the start point (moving, shrinking, or growing). Thus, although your plan isn't the riskiest way to do it (assuming you'd shrink from the end), it's not the safest, either. It's better to partition the disk with free (unpartitioned) space to begin with.